# Setting http status code with php

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-codes

When setting a custom status code response with PHP using `header()` is:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

Correct, or:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
```

Which is the `http` standard? Or, should you set both?

Comment: The second one is correct. The first is not a valid http header to my knowledge, it would be "HTTP/1.0 404 Page Not Found"
You could almost view it as "<httpversion> <httpcode> <httptext>"

Comment: @Justin, Your answer is already there in the link Gould posted.

Answer (score 2):

I have generally set error codes like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```